# CardLayout performance?

Tags: java, swing, vector, jpanel, cardlayout

I thought that CardLayout uses a HashMap to store its pairs (panels and associated string identifiers) but looking through the CardLayout class I noticed that it actually uses a Vector. This is how I understand it: when the `show` method is called it loops through the contents of the vector checking with `equals` to find out if this is the name of the appropriate card, and if it is, it then loops through all the panels of the container to find out which one is currently visible, it hides it, and then it displays the appropriate card.

If I was making a gui app that has a *lot* of different panels wouldn't that be kind of slow technique to flip to the desired panel? Should I better use my own way of showing my panels like storing them to an array and manually using `add`/`remove` or `setVisible` instead of using CardLayout? This is actually the way I was using at the beginning before I ended up to CardLayout.

Comment: It is *relatively* slow compared to hashing if you are getting components randomly, but it is fast if you are getting them sequentially. Having said this, its performance still is pretty darn fast. Are you sure by use of profiling that this is causing a significant bottleneck in your GUI's actual and perceived performance? If not, then we're just debating about the number of angels who can dance on the head of a pin.

Comment: No I didn't try to measure it but it just seems a lot slower than the manual way, which is not that complex anyway. Why is it fast if we're getting the components sequentially? If I am currently at the 18th card and I want to get the 19th, the show method will still loop from the beginning (twice), or not?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, you were probably talking about next() but this also loops through the components until it finds the appropriate one. It just loops once instead of twice.

Comment: If you're really concerned about the performance of the `CardLayout`, you could roll your own, using a `Map<String, Component>` and a `BorderLayout`, bu, as Hovercraft has pointed, unless you're really seeing a massive slow down between switches (that isn't related to repaint issues), why bother :P

Comment: Well I'm not using 50 panels yet for my app but when I do maybe I'll go back to my own way of showing them. I just thought that there was an important benefit of CardLayout (except simplicity) that I was missing here, that's why I asked...

Comment: What you call a lot is probably almost nothing for a computer. If it has to go sequentially through 1000 items in a `Vector` we are probably still talking about milliseconds (if not even faster). For a UI that is pretty fast, and will most likely never be the bottleneck in your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will **never be an issue**: you don't normally flip between components very frequently, and when you do then scanning a list with a smallish number of compoenents (usually 3-100?) is going to take a negligible amount of time compared with other operations that will have to happen (e.g. drawing the new component). Choice of data structure is basically irrelevant from a performance perspective - you could use a linked list and nobody would notice.

Also note that a **HashMap wouldn't be appropriate** for a CardLayout as it needs to preserve the *order* of the cards so that you can use `first`/`next`/`previous` etc.

So basically, don't worry and don't waste your time rolling your own CardLayout clone - CardLayout works just fine.

Comment: I see... I changed the accepted answer to this one because of the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any performance issue in CardLayout. Even if you have a 1000 child components, it still feels very fast. Either by using previous/next or using show, it goes really fast.

Try to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces your problem and then we may help you. Here is something to start from:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestCardLayout {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            panel.add(new JLabel("Label " + i), getLabelConstraint(i));
        }
        JButton next = new JButton("Next");
        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                layout.next(panel);
            }
        });
        JButton previous = new JButton("Previous");
        previous.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                layout.previous(panel);
            }
        });
        final JButton choose = new JButton("Choose");
        choose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(choose, "Enter a number between 0 and 999");
                try {
                    int i = Integer.valueOf(value);
                    if (i > -1 && i < 1000) {
                        layout.show(panel, getLabelConstraint(i));
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(previous);
        buttonPanel.add(next);
        buttonPanel.add(choose);

        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private String getLabelConstraint(int i) {
        return "ComponentConstraint" + i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestCardLayout().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a problem actually... I'm just making an app that will use a lot of panels and 

I was considering to go back to my old way of showing panels when I saw how CardLayout 

manages the flipping between cards. It just seemed to me slow, that's all... Like I said in 

a comment I thought that there was an other benefit of CardLayout, except simplicity, that I was missing. Based on the comments and your answer I guess that even if it is (theoretically) slower it is not perceivable.